# How to get PyDev to work with multiple top level packages in one project

Tags: python, pydev

Environment: python 3.9.6, PyDev 8.3, Eclipse 2020-12, Windows 10

I've working with one top-level package project till now; and all is good.
My source code directory is like the following:

```
git-project-name (root folder of the project)
    pkg1 
        __init__.py
        common.py
        main.py
        (other .py files, no sub-folder)
```

Now, I want to add a root level package to the project, so the directory structure would be:

```
git-project-name (root folder of the project)
    pkg1 
        __init__.py
        common.py
        main.py
        (other .py files, no sub-folder)
    pkg2
        __init__.py
        (some .py files here)
        sub_pkg1
            __init__.py
            (some .py files here)

    resources
        (some data files, with sub_folders)
```

In the serup.cfg, I have the following

```
[metadata]
name = pkg1

[options]
python_requires = >=3.8
zip_safe = False
include_package_data = True
packages=find:

[options.package_data]
tele2=resources/tele2
```

The setup.cfg and setup.py are fine, when I run ***python setup.py sdist***, all the .py files and resources files are packed into the .tar.gz file.

My problem is, in .py file under pkg1, I can import modules from pkg2 with no problem; but in .py file under pkg2, I cannot import modules from pkg1. I'll get runtime error like the following:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg1.common'; 'pkg1' is not a package
```

If I open the exact same project in PyCharm or VSCode, and run the exact code, everything works fine.
I tried to figure out if it's just a configuration issue in PyDev, but could not find out what I'm missing in my configure.

Thanks

Comment: I believe that what you're missing is properly configuring your source folder for PyDev.

Please take a look at https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html for instructions. If you still can't figure it out, please provide a screenshot of the PyDev package explorer showing your project.

Comment: It was the source folder configure in .pydevproject indeed. Thanks @Fabio. The source folder was pointing to /${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}/pkg1 for some reason. Hand-edited .pydevproject to change it to /${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}, now it works as expected.